# Сортировка данных в mysql

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Как правильно отсортировать данные которые извлекаются из БД?
В таблице есть поле field, при извлечении с сортировкой следующим способом:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `field`+0
```

Данные на выходе следующие:

- folder 2
- folder 1
- folder 4
- folder 3

Каким запросом можно отсортировать так:

- folder 1
- folder 2
- folder 3
- folder 4

?

При сортировке

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `field`
```

Данные в этой же таблице другого типа, выводятся так:

- 1.jpg
- 10.jpg
- 100.jpg
- 1000.jpg
- 1001.jpg
- 1002.jpg
- 1003.jpg
- 1006.jpg

Как же сделать, чтобы данные и того и того типа сортировались адекватно?

Comment: может тебе просто хранить файлы и папки в двух разных таблицах? избавит от многочисленного гемора постоянно распознавать папка у тебя в руках или файл. да и структура получше будет выглядеть.

Comment: затем при обычной сортировке SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `field`, папки будут в нужном тебе порядке

Comment: @Стас Казанин, не вариант, так как потом с постраничной навигацией будут траблы, а переписывать навигацию ой как не хочется, наверняка должен быть способ решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо подстроку от первого символа до точки (исключительно) привести к INTEGER и сортировать по этому числу. Правда, при этом потеряется индексация этого поля, если она вообще есть.

```
...order by to_number(substr(field, 1, Pos(field, '.') - 1))
```

Как-то так. Извините, подзабыл синтаксис SQL, но идея верна. Так что осталось лишь творчески преломить :-)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, попробую Ваш вариант

Comment: FUNCTION to_number does not exist

я так понимаю такая функция не везде есть?